# How to print mass amounts of text in a single string in java

Tags: java, eclipse, printing

I'm looking for a way to print the entire script to a movie, which has multiple lines returned after the first line in the print statement. If I try to use the format of code below, it errors out, and doesn't count all the text after the first line as a string. How do I format it correctly without having to add quotations and +'s at the end of each line, or without having to backspace and put everything on one line?

```
  System.out.println("Movie title
    more text
    more text
    more text");
```

Edit: I am not a pro at java. I want to know if it's possible to do it with just a simple print statement, and not other classes or methods im not familiar with.

Comment: If you work on your search skills, it will help your Java skills.

Comment: *"I am not a pro at java ..."* - We gathered as much.  If you want to get to even amateur status, you would be advised to read the Oracle Java Tutorials - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/.  At least, read the streams that cover the basics.  (The question you asked is actually a very basic Java syntax question.)